# Most recent entry of a record in an Access report

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I am trying to retrieve the most recent entry of a record in an Access report.  The query I have gives me the results in SQL-Server but row_number is not compatible with Access.  Its been suggested that I use the max function in Access.  Can you assist me in generating this report?

```
SELECT  cID, CName, Address,  Project#, JobOwner, SubStatusID,  Status, JNJobID, JNNote
FROM (
    SELECT
      cID, CName, Address,  Project#, JobOwner, SubStatusID,  Status, JNJobID, JNNote
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JNJobID ORDER BY JNDate DESC) AS r
    FROM [JobNotes] 
    Left JOIN Jobs ON [JobNotes].JNJobID = Jobs.JobID
    Left JOIN Addresses ON Jobs.JobAddressID = Addresses.AddressID
    Left JOIN Customers ON Jobs.JobCustomerID = Customers.CID 
    Left JOIN Status ON Jobs.JobSubStatusID = Status.StatusID
) x 
WHERE r = 1 and customerID = 134 and jobsubstatusid <> 14 and jobsubstatusid <> 15 and jobsubstatusid <> 16 and jobsubstatusid <> 42 and jobsubstatusid <>38 and jobsubstatusid <>75
```

Jobs Table

```
JobID   Project#     JobOwner       JobStatusID  AddressID JobCustomerID
 6972   PN1            John                1          333        222
 6973   PN2            Sarah               3          444        666 
 6974   PN3            James               6          555        777
```

Address Table

```
 AddressID        Address
    333         1333 Janes Ln
    444         5555 Davis Blvd
    555         888 Post Rd
```

Customer Table

```
    CID         CName
    222         Builder
    666         HomeOwner
    777         HOA
```

JobNotes Table

```
JobNotesID  JNJobID JNDate                       JNNote    
 11800      6972    2016-03-15 00:00:00.000     Example 1
 11874      6972    2016-03-17 00:00:00.000     Example 2
 12181      6972    2016-03-25 00:00:00.000     Example 3
 12006      6973    2016-03-21 00:00:00.000     Example 4
 11961      6974    2016-03-18 00:00:00.000     Example 5
 11924      6974    2016-03-17 00:00:00.000     Example 6
```

JobNotes Table

```
CID  CName     Address          Project#  JobOwner SubStatusID Status      JNJobID JNNote 
222  Builder    1333 Janes Ln    PN1       John     1          Sales         6972  Example 3
666  HomeOwner  5555 Davis Blvd  PN2       Sarah    3          Design        6973  Example 4
777  HOA        888 Post Rd      PN3       James    6          Construction  6974  Example 6
```

Comment: Is the data in Access or sql server? This is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The backend is SQL- Server but the report is being generated in MS Access 2010.  When I put the query in Access the report does not work because of row_number.

Comment: If the data is in sql server can you just use a stored procedure in sql server as the datasource for your report?

Comment: In Access you simply use `SELECT TOP 1` with appropriate sorting.

Comment: Will select Top 1 work if I have multiple joins?

Comment: Top 1 will not work here. You are trying to get the top 1 for each Job, not the entire table. The number of joins makes no difference however.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?